# what does this syntax mean? words = [stemmer.stem(w.lower()) for w in words if w != "?"]

Tags: python

I'm learning python+chatbot from [this site](https://techwithtim.net/tutorials/ai-chatbot/part-2/).

I came across this python syntax I'm not sure what it does.

```py
words = [stemmer.stem(w.lower()) for w in words if w != "?"]
```

Could you please let me know, especially the bracket+expression+space+expression+bracket?
words = [stemmer.stem(w.lower()) for w in words if w != "?"]

I tried these in the python interpreter but still can't guess the logic of the syntax:

```
In [25]: words=[1 for i in [1,2,3] if i !=2]

In [26]: words
Out[26]: [1, 1]

In [27]: words=[2 for i in [1,2,3] if i !=2]

In [28]: words
Out[28]: [2, 2]


In [32]: a=[0 1]
```

yield invalid syntax (I tried to post the exact message, but the form complains about the format)

Comment: That syntax is called List comprehensions https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions